# Pegar o valor de um botão do tipo radio com Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, front-end

Como selecionar um botão radio usando JS puro e pegar o valor definido pelo usuário?

Segue meu código HTML:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cadastro" id="professorCadastro" value="professor">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="professorCadastro">Professor</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cadastro" id="alunoCadastro" value="aluno">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="alunoCadastro">Aluno</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cadastro" id="empresaCadastro" value="empresa" disabled>
     <label class="form-check-label" for="empresaCadastro">Empresa</label>
</div>
```

Segue me JS até o momento

```
let tipoCadastro = document.getElementsByName('cadastro')
```

Comment: Valina Javascript não seria Vanilla Javascript ?

Comment: Onde é que o "usuário" define alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o `value` de uma coleção de `radio button`, você pode criar um evento click para cada um e pegar seu respectivo valor ao clicar nele:

```js
// pego todos os radios com name=cadastro
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'][name='cadastro']");
for(var x=0; x<radios.length; x++){
   radios[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var valor = this.value;
      console.log(valor);
   });
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cadastro" id="professorCadastro" value="professor">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="professorCadastro">Professor</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cadastro" id="alunoCadastro" value="aluno">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="alunoCadastro">Aluno</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cadastro" id="empresaCadastro" value="empresa" disabled>
     <label class="form-check-label" for="empresaCadastro">Empresa</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A função [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) devolve um `NodeList`, que é como se fosse um array de elementos com esse nome. Isso faz com que tenha que aceder ao primeiro, na posição `0` ou alternativamente utilizar um laço/ciclo para percorrer os vários elementos e fazer alguma coisa com eles.

Assumindo que apenas tem um elemento com esse nome, pode aceder ao valor com:

```
let valor = document.getElementsByName('cadastro')[0].value;
//                                                 ^ ---- primeiro
```

No entanto, se já tem `id` no elemento, simplifique e utilize [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), que o mesmo já não acontece, pois só apanha um elemento, uma vez que o `id` tem de ser único.

Comment: Show.. esse funcionou... mas precisava de algo mais dinâmico.
Consegui aqui com a informação abaixo!